# Get my app to launch another app with parameters

Tags: cordova

From my android hybrid app (cordova/phonegap) I want to launch the media player and play an rtsp stream comming from an ip-camera.

I first confirmed that the player can play the stream by launching it from adb:

```
adb shell
am start -n com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d rtsp://root:1@10.253.253.2/axis-media/media.amp
```

To get it to run from my app, I thought that this plugin may help...

https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

But I cant figure out how to translate what appears in the adb command into what is required by this plugin.

E.g. I have tried many things including...

```
// cordova plugin add https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp.git
navigator.startApp.start(
    ["com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity", 
    ["-d rtsp://root:1@10.253.253.2/axis-media/media.amp"]],  
function(message) { 
   console.log("start: " + message); 
}, 
function(error) { 
    console.log("start " + error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigator.startApp.start([
    ["com.android.gallery3d", "com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity"],
    ["rtsp://root:1@10.253.253.2/axis-media/media.amp"]
], function(message) {
    console.log(message); // => OK
}, 
function(error) { /* error */
    console.log(error);
});
```